# how to create n number of array whenever whenever user click a button

Tags: flutter, dart

whenever user press a button i want to create:

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier =
ValueNotifier([]);

when click once more:

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier1 =
ValueNotifier([]);

when click once more:

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier2 =
ValueNotifier([]);

then so on..